# How to use 'dir' to different folders in one command?

Tags: powershell, cmd, dir

Any ideas how to use the command 'dir' to more than 1 folder in one command?

```
dir c:\A | c:\test\B
```

is not working. Im not good with pipes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet instead, or use DIR and separate your sources by commas, not spaces.  DIR doesn't work the same in PowerShell as it does in a DOS window.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx

Comment: yeah now I see, in powershell I need to use ",". Funny, I can even say 'ls c:\A , c:\test\B'

Comment: dir = gci = ls = get-childitem. They are all aliases to get-childitem. I've updated your answer to disambiguate.

Comment: @x0n I thought about your edit but reverted it; since the DIR alias doesn't appear to work with multiple sources (see Nick Hartung's answer below), it is clearly not equivalent, and my second sentence addresses a different point.

Comment: dir in powershell works with multiple sources, as does dir in cmd. It's just that the former is comma separated, the latter by space.

Answer (score 1):

`dir c:\A c:\test\B` should work. No pipe necessary.

Comment: Thank you. Funny, this is working with cmd but not with powershell. Thought dir is everywhere the same.

Comment: I didn't realize that this was a powershell question as first glance. Apparently both "dir" and "ls" are aliases for PowerShell's Get-ChildItem cmdlet according to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692685.aspx#EGAA). So there are probably some slight differences.

Comment: No thats fine. Powershell or cmd, if I know how to use it im happy

Comment: You need a comma between c:\A and c:\test\B, not a space.